# Force.com Scanner not working

Tags: security-scanner

We are trying to use force.com code scanner for security check.We have provided the credentials of our org multiple times,but each time when we try scanning our org,it shows the same  error every time

> Due to high volume, users may only have one scan pending at any given time. Please wait for your current scan to finish. We apologize for any inconvenience

Experts Please suggest

Comment: Sounds like one of your requests is queued but you may have to wait days for the results. What makes you think the message is wrong? See the long wait this OP is experiencing [Is it that there are alternatives to the security scan salesforce?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130245/is-it-that-there-are-alternatives-to-the-security-scan-salesforce).

Comment: You say you provided the credentials "multiple times" but then complain that you get an error that you "may only have one scan pending at any given time"?? The error seems perfectly consistent with the behavior you describe. As Keith said, you simply have to wait for the original pending scan to process.

Comment: You can check following thread as it is a similar situation. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130120/security-scanner-not-giving-updates/130124#130124

Comment: Thanks,But the problem is that when we tried scanning our org for the first time it showed us the same error.

Comment: @SebastianKessel, i too tried for the first time submitting to the scanner, unfortunately ended up with the same error. Any thoughts?